# in flutter with dart I have a problem , The receiver can't be null, so the null-aware operator '?.' is unnecessary

Tags: flutter, dart

```
**I have a problem with this code:** The receiver can't be null, so the null-aware operator '?.' is unnecessary. this is appear when I execution the above code
```

[image]

please help me if u know anything about this problem

```
    var activeVoteId = Provider.of<VoteState>(context).activeVote?.voteId ?? '';
```

Answer (score 1):

`activeVote` initialize with null-able and remove the `late` keyword. Otherwise, initialize when you declare the `activeVote`

```
DataType ? activeVote;
```

if you use follow the the given example

```
late DataType  activeVote = initValue;
//like
late String value = "";
```

Comment: follow the link for late initialization https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312956/flutter-late-keyword-with-declaration/69313493#69313493

Comment: I do not understand ???
Can you write my code correctly so that the error disappears?

Comment: Share your activevote provider code part

Comment: Function alternateColor = getAlternate(start: 0);

   String activeVoteId = Provider.of<VoteState>(context).activeVote?.voteId ?? '';

Comment: try with this `String activeVoteId = Provider.of<VoteState>(context)?.activeVote?.voteId ?? ''`

Comment: `activeVote`  code part from your provider