# How can I use widget parameters as variables?

Tags: flutter, dart

I cant use the parameter variable.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.userState,
    required this.currentPageForRoute,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool userState;
  final int currentPageForRoute;


  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
```

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
int currentPage = widget.currentPageForRoute;

//And then, i going to change currentPage often and use it.

}
```

I want use widget.currentPageForRoute as currentPage variable, but i cant.
(If I can use it, I will change it often.)
The error massage: Undefined name 'widget'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initState` method or `late`

```dart
late int currentPage = widget.currentPageForRoute;
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [late keyword with declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69312956/10157127)