# the instance member 'params' can't be accessed in an initializer for API Key

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dart-null-safety

Here I have attached an API response parsing model. Which I need do more refactoring by dividing the category , country and apikey. I have created a variable as apikey and assigned near to the apikey string. but the error shown as:

***code***

```
class ApiServiceBusiness {

  final category1 = "";
  
  final apiKey = "df892d97b60e454db3f5ba14f4a4b12d";

  dynamic endPointUrla = Uri.parse("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=business&apiKey=$apiKey");

  Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
    Response res1 = await get(endPointUrla);

    if (res1.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res1.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];

      List<Article> articlesBusiness = body.map((dynamic  item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
      
      return articlesBusiness;
    } else {
      throw ("Can't get the articles");
    }
  }
}
```

***error***:
**The instance member 'apiKey' can't be accessed in an initializer.**

> how to refactor the apikey, category and courtry each by each string. Thank You.

Comment: could you add your code too?

Comment: yeah editted and added.

Answer (score 1):

Make `apiKey` static like this:

```
static final apiKey = "df892d97b60e454db3f5ba14f4a4b12d";
```

you only allow use static variable in initializer.

Comment: yes its working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `late`

```dart
late dynamic endPointUrla = Uri.parse(...)
```

More about  [late keyword with declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69312956/10157127)