# How to use if else in bottom navigation for screens in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here in my code **mapResponse** is a variable which can be null, so I want to check and if the mapResponse is null I want the page to navigate to different page in bottom navigation, below given is the code, but it throws the error saying **"The instance member 'mapResponse' can't be accessed in an initializer."**

```
Map? mapResponse

     final screens = [
        const LandingPage(),
        const ComingSoon(),
        const ComingSoon(),
        mapResponse==null?const ProfileDashBoard():const Home()
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
Map? mapResponse

List screens = [];
initState((){
        screens =[
        const LandingPage(),
        const ComingSoon(),
        const ComingSoon(),
        mapResponse==null?const ProfileDashBoard():const Home()
      ];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee do it in `initState` like this:

```
  Map? mapResponse;
  List screens = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    screens = [
      const LandingPage(),
      const ComingSoon(),
      const ComingSoon(),
      mapResponse == null ? const ProfileDashBoard() : const Home(),
    ];
  }
```

Comment: was it what you want? @Mr.Robot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `late`

```
late final screens = [
```

More about  [late keyword with declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69312956/10157127)